# Creating private queues in PowerShell on Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows, powershell, server, windows-server-2008-r2

I googled how to do this and I found this code:

```
Write-Host "... create a new queue"
$q1 = [System.Messaging.MessageQueue]::Create(".\private$\myqueues")

Write-Host "... create new queue, set FullControl permissions for queuename"
$qb =[System.Messaging.MessageQueue]::Create(".\private$\queuename")

$qb.SetPermissions("queuename", 
  [System.Messaging.MessageQueueAccessRights]::FullControl,            
  [System.Messaging.AccessControlEntryType]::Set)
```

but when I run it, I get this error:

```
Unable to find type [System.Messaging.MessageQueueAccessRights]. Make sure 
 that the assembly that contains this type is loaded.
At line:7 char:1
+ $qb.SetPermissions("hazeljob",
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo: InvalidOperation:(System.Messagin...eueAccessRi 
ghts:TypeName) [], RuntimeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound
```

I thought it might be because Message Queuing wasn't installed but then I installed it and still got this error.

Why is this happening? Is this code not compatible with Windows Server 2008 R2? I input my company values over the ones that were in there originally.

Comment: i have not. i will try that.

Comment: i tried it and got this error: Exception calling "SetPermissions" with "3" argument(s): "Could not resolve 
name companyname (error = 1332 )."
At line:9 char:1
+ $qb.SetPermissions("companyname",
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException .         the queues were created but the full access was not granted.

Comment: ohhh no thats just what we call our private queues. so i have to make that value a username?

Comment: so anywhere it says '$qb' i should put the username and where it says '$q1" i should put the queue name? i clearly did not understand this code enough before.

Comment: If you already have a named MessageQueue instance (such as `$q1` or `$qb`), you don't need to supply the queue name again. If you wan't to give FullControl rights to the same user on both queues, you call `SetPermissions()` with the exact same arguments on both `$q1` and `$qb`

Comment: Let's stop this comment madness, I've added an answer instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have two problems with your code.

First, you need to tell PowerShell to import the `System.Messaging` namespace code from the Global Assembly Cache:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Messaging") | Out-Null
```

Next, when using `SetPermission` on a `MessageQueue` instance, you don't need to supply the queue name again - it already knows who it is, so to speak.

What you *do* need to supply is the username of the user, security group or computer to whom you want to grant access to the message queue.

So, if you wanted to grant your own user account FullControll access on the queue "MyQueue", and your username is "david.wilson", that becomes:

```
$Queue = [System.Messaging.MessageQueue]::Create(".\private$\MyQueue")
$Queue.SetPermissions("david.wilson",[System.Messaging.MessageQueueAccessRights]::FullControl, [System.Messaging.AccessControlEntryType]::Set)
```

Comment: alright thanks! i have to officially get this working before i say im done, i just got the variable for current username on the system and just copying and pasting it into where the username would normally go is not working. i suppose ill have to open up a separate question for that lol. sorry for the endless convo i didnt realize stackoverflow had a convo limiter, im new here.

Comment: @DavidWilson The entire idea about StackExchange is to simly ask questions and get questions, not a lot of chit chat :) Feel free to ask a new question about why SetPermissions() doesn't work as you expect

Comment: i know why i did get it! cus there was an extra line of code there that wasnt needed and it was confusing me, i removed it and it worked! lol

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully Server 2008 instances have been or are being decommissioned at this point, but at any rate you can also use Powershell 5 to create queues.

```
function CreateQueue(
    [string] $queueName,
    [string] $queueType = 'Private'
) {
    New-MsmqQueue -Name $queueName -QueueType $queueType
}   

CreateQueue -queueName 'PrivateTestQueue'
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/msmq/new-msmqqueue?view=win10-ps