# Powershell script for server 2008 to get MSMQ security property values

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2008, acl, msmq, windows-server

I'm looking to write a PowerShell script to verify the security configuration of MSMQ on some of our servers, e.g. the contents of the Security tab when I run compmgmt.msc, then go to Computer Management (local) -> Services and Applications -> Message Queueing, then right-click -> Properties -> Security tab.

Note that this is not the same as Service Security (which I'm aware I can retrieve via Get-WmiObject -Query 'SELECT * FROM win32_service' | % PathName | Get-Acl.

MSMQ apparently has its own unique ACL set and custom permissions which I want to query to ensure that certain Service Principals have the correct permissions as part of a release script.

Does anybody know how to access these custom permissions ON WINDOWS SERVER 2008 ? I'm also aware that there's an MSMQ PowerShell module, but it's only available in 2012 and later versions of Windows Server.

Answer (score 0):

You can import the System.Messaging assembly and use the .NET methods directly. You find a code example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33807521/creating-private-queues-in-powershell-on-windows-server-2008-r2) on SO...

Comment: By using.net messaging method you can only set permission but I want to retrieve the users and group of each messaging queue